# AWS Elasticsearch Service: Proper Way to Write this Access Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam

I have a service that makes a DescribeElasticsearchDomain call to a specific domain on startup (to get the URI) and that call is failing.

I find it a little confusing because the domain has an Access Policy which I believe opens it for DescribeElasticsearchDomain to anything from AWS (honestly, this may be where the code below is wrong - the way it is written is a little suspicious).

Here's the error:

`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [classname]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.elasticsearch.model.AWSElasticsearchException: User: arn:aws:sts::{account-id}:assumed-role/{long-role-info} is not authorized to perform: es:DescribeElasticsearchDomain on resource: arn:aws:es:{region}:{account-id}:domain/{domain-name} (Service: AWSElasticsearch; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 22e29929-3c70-11e9-97e9-edb3ab09a546)`

And the Access Policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:DescribeElasticsearchDomain",
        "es:DescribeElasticsearchDomains"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:{region}:{account-id}:domain/{domain-name}/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone know how to do this correctly?

EDIT: I will include also the code for the call being made

```
    private static String fetchElasticUri(String env) {
        AWSElasticsearch awsElasticsearch = AWSElasticsearchClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        DescribeElasticsearchDomainRequest describeElasticsearchDomainRequest = new DescribeElasticsearchDomainRequest()
            .withDomainName(domain-name);
        DescribeElasticsearchDomainResult describeElasticsearchDomainResult = awsElasticsearch.describeElasticsearchDomain(describeElasticsearchDomainRequest);
        ElasticsearchDomainStatus elasticsearchDomainStatus = describeElasticsearchDomainResult.getDomainStatus();
        return "https://" + elasticsearchDomainStatus.getEndpoints().get("vpc");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource policy (attached to the es domain) allows for anyone to perform the actions (es:Describe....) but does the role that the code is using allow the entity assuming the role to perform (es:Describe...)? Without explicitly allowing it there is an implicit deny on es actions.

Add an es:* to the role policy and retest your scenario.

Comment: This is the correct answer - we had solved already. For more info: For whatever reason, that access policy will allow any IAM User access, but requires explicit allow for any Role. Also, if any find this question by googling in the future, note the `/*` at the end of the arn in the access policy. Without this it won't work. Good luck finding anything about this in AWS documentation.